# Windows Phone - find out user state when abandon App

Tags: audio, google-analytics, windows-phone, playback, user-tracking

Want to know who can I **track with** Google Analytics **what is user state** (for example run music track, start watching movie) when he clicked on home, or back button and **abandon** App?

Want to know **reason**, why user left App and **how long** was he running it before left.

Answer (score 0):

You can not Know Why user has left Your app but you can track User's action into to Your app.

For Tracking Add a single line of code to your app for each event you want to track. Here are examples of the different types of activities you can track in your app:

```
// track a page view
GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendView("main");

// track a custom event
GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendEvent("test", "userclick", null, 0);

// manually track an exception
GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendException("oops, something went wrong", false);

// track a transaction (in app purchase)
double cost = 1.99;
long costInMicrons = (long)(cost * 1000000);
var transaction = new GoogleAnalytics.Transaction("01234", costInMicrons);
var item = new GoogleAnalytics.TransactionItem("myproduct", "My Product", costInMicrons, 1);
transaction.Items.Add(item);
GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendTransaction(transaction);

// track a social networking interaction
GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendSocial("facebook", "share", "http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com");

// track a timing (how long it takes your app to run a specific task)
GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendTiming(DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime), "Startup", "MainPage", "Label");
```

For More Refrence you can go [Google Analytics SDK for Windows 8 and Windows Phone](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/)